# Error: the expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment Matlab

Tags: matlab

```
solve(t*(t+0.09)*(t+484)*(t+10000)=1,t)
```

Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.

I write this code on command window and it shows an error

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the double equal sign in the equation `==`. It is clear by reading the [documentation](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) of `solve`:

> **Solve an Equation**
>
> Use the == operator to specify the equation sin(x) == 1 and solve it.

Additionally, you have to declare the symbolic variable `t` before attempting to solve the equation. The final code should look like this:

```
syms t
solve(t*(t+0.09)*(t+484)*(t+10000) == 1, t)
```